# Get patch'd object with use of unittest.mock's patch decorator and new

Tags: python, monkeypatching, python-unittest.mock

I have the below `Python==3.8` code, where I:

- Use `unittest.mock.patch` as a decorator
- Preform a `patch(..., new=...)`:

```py
from unittest.mock import patch

class Foo:
    pass

class Bar:
    pass

@patch(__name__ + f".Foo", new=Bar)
def test_foo(patched_Bar) -> None:
    _ = 0  # Do stuff
```

Currently, this doesn't run, as the `patched_Bar` argument is not supplied.  How can I get the `patched_Bar` arg to be passed in?

I know the below workaround exists, using `with`, but I prefer not to do this, as it's less clean in my opinion.

```py
def test_foo2() -> None:
    with patch(__name__ + f".Foo", new=Bar) as patched_Bar:
        _ = 0  # Do stuff
```

Answer (score 0):

This is not needed, because you already have the patched class, e.g. `Bar` in your case. You get the same if you use the context manager, as you can see:

```py
def test_foo() -> None:
    with patch(f"{__name__}.Foo", new=Bar) as patched_Bar:
        assert patched_bar == Bar
```

May be you are thinking about getting an instance of `Bar` instead, but that cannot work, because the instance will be created only inside the test.

The difference with a default mock is that you can set `return_value` to the mocked class, and each instantiation of the class will get you the same instance:

```py
@patch(f"{__name__}.Foo")
def test_foo(patched_foo) -> None:
    foo1 = Foo()
    foo2 = Foo()
    assert patched_foo.return_value == foo1 == foo2
    assert isinstance(foo1, MagicMock)
```

while with a replacement class which is not a mock this won't work:

```py
@patch(f"{__name__}.Foo", Bar)
def test_foo() -> None:
    foo1 = Foo()
    foo2 = Foo()
    assert foo1 != foo2
    assert isinstance(foo1, Bar)
```